# How to pass different parameters from a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have 3 models as category, posts and comments. I want to display posts and number of comments in the category page.

`category.(:id)Post.(:id).comments.count` will return the number of comments.

But how should I pass those parameters from category controller? I'm also trying to write the jbuilder view for the same.

or Can I do something like this directly from jbuilder view?

```html
#this work

json.number @category.posts.count

#this one doesn't work

json.number @category.posts.comments.count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.number @category.posts.count` it works but 
`json.number @category.posts.comments.count` this does not.

You can test in rails console.. like `@category.posts.comments.count`.
it may throw error like
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'comments' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Post:0x0000000920b058>`

This happens because `@category.posts` returns a collection not `Post` object.

One possible solution is
`@category.posts.map {|post| [post, post.comments.count] }`
This gives you the total count of comments per post in array. This may not be exactly what you wanted but you may modify to meet your requirement.

Comment: Your solution will provide the total number comments, I want to get the number of comments for each posts separately.

What I'm trying to build is a `category.json.jbuilder` file which provides a collection of each posts and its properties, I also want to include the number of each post along with that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass parameters from the controller to a view you are going to present is using the @ (instance variable). Therefore you can pass:

```
@count = <your code above>
@all_posts = <your post code>
```

If you have alot of different parameters, just create an object to pass them across in:

```
@post_info = {
      count: <your code above>,
      all_posts: <your post code>
}
```

And then retrieve them in your view using @post_info[:count] and @post_info[:all_posts]

Comment: the problem is, I only have access to category_id in the category controller.